# conditional promise before then()

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to use one promise to retrieve some data before continue with the logical of my code.

The thing ins i try to use this:

```
if (label === 'edit') {
    new skill_watson_export_no_append(jsonSkillIntentsUpdate, id_skill_tst).update_skill_no_append(jsonSkillIntentsUpdate, id_skill_tst)
} else {
    new skill_watson_export(new_intent_preprocess, id_skill_tst).update_skill_append(new_intent_preprocess, id_skill_tst)
}.then(response_watson => {
```

but i have an error 'Declaration or statment expected'

i need to use one of this promises before continue, if not the only way is to repeat 200 lines of code.
Someone help me....?
thanks

Comment: it's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but if I'm understanding correctly, then you can just conditionally assign one of these two promises to a variable and then do `myPromiseVariable.then(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin why you vote me negative? i am learning, and i have a doubt, just help or not, but not punish. :-(

Answer (score 2):

`if` statements don't provide a value when they are evaluated. You can't follow on with a method call.

You could use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
(
    (label === 'edit') ?
        new skill_watson_export_no_append(jsonSkillIntentsUpdate, id_skill_tst).update_skill_no_append(jsonSkillIntentsUpdate, id_skill_tst) :
        new skill_watson_export(new_intent_preprocess, id_skill_tst).update_skill_append(new_intent_preprocess, id_skill_tst)
).then( ... )
```

But, frankly, that is rather unwieldy, and assigning the promise to a variable declared with `let` would probably be easier to manage.

Breaking the logic out into its own function that returns the apropriate promise would likely be even easier to maintain.

Comment: why the if else is wrong and the ternary works? where is my mistake? :_()

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions that's explained in the first sentence of this answer. If you want to know more, look up the difference between statements and expressions in Javascript (which is the same in most other programming languages). In short, `if ... else` is a statement, but a ternary is an expression - and only expressions evaluate to something which you can then perform further operations on (like, in your case, a `.then` method call).

Comment: @Quentin, not works with parentesis, only works without them.